# Delete Network processes hung up

Tags: google-compute-engine

Deleting network request hung up and it's not stopping.  It's causing my rate limit to be exceeded and I can't even see the list of operations.

Comment: PROJECT ID REQUESTS  ERRORS  CHARGES 

prime-framing-851 262,223 259,030 $0.00

Answer (score 0):

Finally the hung API requests stopped after 550k request, about 150 requests per sec. Not sure if this is a bug....